# Sending `Refresh` with no listeners registered.-- React-native

Tags: ios, react-native

Sending `Refresh` with no listeners registered.

```
@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: RCTEventEmitter  {
    override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
        return ["Refresh"]
    }
}
```

import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

```
const myModuleEvt = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyModule)
myModuleEvt.addListener("Refresh", (xyz) => console.log("hey"))
```

It seems I have done everything as per doc but I am still getting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since this was asked and a shame there were no answers because this could have helped me too. I was having the exact same problem and none of the answers posted fixed my problem. What finally did was to call [super initWithDisabledObservation] in my class' init method instead of just [super init].

I looked at RCTEventEmitter.m source code. The source of the problem is:

BOOL shouldEmitEvent = (_observationDisabled || _listenerCount > 0);

It seems like in my case _listenerCount was never getting updated when my JS code added listeners for the events. And because of that sendEventWithName never even called the relevant code to send the event back to javascript and just instead gave me this warning. But when calling [super initWithDisabledObservation], _observationDisabled is set to true, so sendEventWithName ignores listener count and always does what it's supposed to.

Comment: But it also has a check in addListener/removeListener:
  if (_observationDisabled) {
    return;
  }
Luckily this method does nothing but check if event is supported and call start/stop observing.

Seems like no one cares.

Comment: Oh, it turns out they did it on purpose https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/82187bfb6b54fdffc5dadaa56e8bf97d2209708a